# Stack corruption when using TSQLConnection.SetTraceEvent?

Tags: delphi, debugging, dbexpress

I've multithreaded application where new TSQLConnection is created for each thread. If I try to use tracing (TSQLConnection.SetTraceEvent or TSQLMonitoring) I get the trace results as expected, but after that the main thread seems to beserk when I try to use any database functionality. Application throws excpetion "access violation at 0x004dffcf: write of address 0xfffffff2" and  the call stack in IDE shows repeating lines of "7c90327a ntdll.RlConvertUlongToLargerInteger + 0x3c" and "7c90e48a ntdll.KiUserExceptionDispatcher + 0xe", and the top line is "Controls.ReadControlName(???)".

So, is the tracing function buggy and doesn't work with multithreaded application or is there hidden bug in my application? How to find out?

I'm using Delphi 2007.

**Edit** It looks like the exception is raised even with two separate connection in main thread. I'll try to create test application.

Comment: You will need to post code...

Comment: DbConnection1.SetTraceEvent(MyEvent) is enough..

Comment: What you want to see? I can't post the whole application, and otherwise is pretty simple. The datamodule which contains the SQL Connection is created multiple times.

Comment: post a sample app or unit that shows this behaviour by querying the `master` database in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I had old (and apparently buggy) version of InterXpress driver loaded, I just didn't realize that it is part of the problem.